# Inline code in comment causes overflow of code container outside of answer/question comment section

Tags: bug, comments, inline-code

Using Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (official Build) (64-bit) on Linux, this happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978486/mongodb-mongoose-query-returns-null-for-aggregate-or-search-with-non-matching#comment92864233_52978885):

[image: screenshot of highlighting extending into the right sidebar]

Comment: This comment displays properly for me when viewed with Firefox 88.0.1 on Windows. Which browser/OS are you using?